# Dune: What titles were used by the heads of Minor Houses during the Empire under House Corrin

Tags: dune

Houses Minor are a well established part of the Dune Universe, being mentioned in passing many times. But I can't recall a single character from a Minor House.

The Siridar Titles of the Major houses are a jumble, Duke, Count, Baron seem to be randomly assigned to houses. Atreides holds a single world (Caladan is a valuable agricultural world) and the Harkonnens hold 2 (Geidi Prime, which surely has a GDP multiple times what Caladan's is, and Lankviel a less important agricultural world) and are governors of the most valuable world (Arrakis), yet Leto is a Duke and Vladimir is just a Baron.

Did the heads of Minor Houses even have a title? If so what were their titles?

Comment: Fenring was the head of a House Minor and was a Count

Comment: Fenring was related to Shadam on his grandmother's side (distaff cousin), possibly that may have accounted him special favour (that and any BG persuasions to consolidate his position.)